# Background image for pgfplots chart

Tags: pgfplots, backgrounds

Following up on the answer to [proper tool for charts in tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116869/proper-tool-for-charts-in-tex) I've built this picture to simulate/replace a scanned image from a newspaper:

[image]

I've tried several ways to put the background newsprint image behind the whole figure (axis labels and titles) as well as the chart, with no success.

When that's done, I'd like to have ragged edges, as in @Ipsens's answer to
[Torn page effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/torn-page-effect/86151#86151)

Here's my MWE (not absolutely minimal, but small enough). The newsprint image is
http://www.theblockforum.com/fun/lance/lancescollection/textures/paper2.jpg

**Edit:** [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) might be helpful, but I couldn't get the example there to compile.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

%deal with warning message in log
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\newcommand{\mywidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\myheight}{7cm}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35872/multiline-coords
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
name, footprint
Google search, 0.2
Movie download, 20
Daily newspaper, 170
}\carbonfootprints

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \includegraphics{newsprint}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\begin{axis}[ 
      xbar, xmin=0,
      tick style={draw=none},
      width=\mywidth, height=\myheight, 
      enlarge y limits=0.5,
      xlabel={Estimated carbon footprint, g CO${}_2$}, 
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={align=right},
      yticklabels={
        Google\\ search, 
        Movie\\ download,
        Daily\\ newspaper,
      },
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
    ]
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=footprint, y expr=\coordindex] 
             {\carbonfootprints};
\end{axis} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is also very beautiful http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52793/3235

Comment: To get sans serif fonts also for the tick labels, you can load the `sansmath` package and use `font=\sffamily\sansmath` (see [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to use the `pencildraw` style from **Ipsens**s answer to do a clipping before the `axis` environment; after the `axis` environment a `\node` is used to include the background image using a `background` layer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

%deal with warning message in log
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\definecolor{paper}{RGB}{239,227,157}

\newcommand{\mywidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\myheight}{7cm}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35872/multiline-coords
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
name, footprint
Google search, 0.2
Movie download, 20
Daily newspaper, 170
}\carbonfootprints

\tikzset{
pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\path[clip,pencildraw] (-2.5,-40pt) rectangle (9,6);
\begin{axis}[
      xbar, xmin=0,
      tick style={draw=none},
      width=\mywidth, height=\myheight, 
      enlarge y limits=0.5,
      xlabel={Estimated carbon footprint, g CO${}_2$}, 
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={align=right},
      yticklabels={
        Google\\ search, 
        Movie\\ download,
        Daily\\ newspaper,
      },
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
    ]
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=footprint, y expr=\coordindex] 
             {\carbonfootprints};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node {\includegraphics{papiro}};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I want from Ipsen's answer is the torn page effect, but with my newsprint image instead of paper color, and the background filling the whole picture, not just the plot itself. Note that in my picture the image does in fact extend a little to the right of the plot.

Comment: @EthanBolker please see my update answer; is it something like that what you want?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina \includegraphics{papiro} ?? :-)

Comment: @Papiro hehe! "Papiro" is the Spanish word for papyrus :-)