# Combine pgfplots on common background

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, backgrounds

This image is two `tikzpicture`s side by side, each with a newsprint background (thanks to [Background image for pgfplots chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118135/background-image-for-pgfplots-chart)).

I want them combined, so they appear on the same torn sheet of newsprint. The title should be centered there, too.

I've looked at answers to several questions about nesting `tikzpicture`s but couldn't solve my problem.

The not quite minimal MWE follows. (Sorry for the details and the duplicated code. I thought it best to provide the actual plots I plan to use.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}

%deal with warning message in log
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\newcommand{\images}{../images}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
year, return, assets
2007, 23, 34.9
2008, 8.6, 37
2009, -27.3, 26
2010, 11, 27.4
2011, 21.4, 32
}\endowment

\newcommand{\plotsize}{width=7cm, height=6cm}

\tikzset{
pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt,amplitude=3pt}
    }, 
font=\sffamily\sansmath
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip,pencildraw] (-1.8,-1) rectangle (6,5.5);
\begin{axis}[ 
      title={\large Harvard Endowment},
      \plotsize,
      ylabel={Return}, 
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=middle,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel style={align=center},
      xticklabels={2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011},
      yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=year, y=return] {\endowment};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node{\includegraphics{\images/newsprint}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip,pencildraw] (-1.8,-1) rectangle (6,5.5);
\begin{axis}[ 
      ymin=0,
      ylabel={Assets}, 
      \plotsize,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel style={align=center},
      xticklabels={2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011},
      yticklabel={\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}b},
      nodes near coords={\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}b},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=year, y=assets] {\endowment};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node{\includegraphics{\images/newsprint}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can place two `axis` environments in one `tikzpicture`. Check section 4.18 “Alignment Options” (pp. 280ff.) in the `pgfplots` manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this, you can put both `axis` environments into the same `tikzpicture` (not in a nested one) with a single large newsprint background. If you name the first axis using `name=left axis`, say, you can position the second one using `at=(left axis.east), anchor=outer west` (the `outer` refers to the anchor that takes all labels into account).

To place the title, it's easiest if you use a normal node outside the second `axis` environment. You can position it precisely in the middle of the two plots by using the `calc` library's coordinate calculation syntax `($(left axis.outer north east)!0.5!(right axis.outer north west)$)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}

%Use the new axis label placement features
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}


\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
year, return, assets
2007, 23, 34.9
2008, 8.6, 37
2009, -27.3, 26
2010, 11, 27.4
2011, 21.4, 32
}\endowment

\newcommand{\plotsize}{width=7cm, height=6cm}

\tikzset{
pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt,amplitude=3pt}
    }, 
font=\sffamily\sansmath
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip,pencildraw] (-2,-1) rectangle (15,6);
\begin{axis}[ 
      name=left axis,
      \plotsize,
      ylabel={Return}, 
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=middle,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel style={align=center},
      xticklabels={2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011},
      yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=year, y=return] {\endowment};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node {\includegraphics[width=30cm]{newsprint}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis} 
\begin{axis}[
      name=right axis,
      at=(left axis.east),
      anchor=outer west,
      xshift=3em,
      ymin=0,
      ylabel={Assets}, 
      \plotsize,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel style={align=center},
      xticklabels={2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011},
      yticklabel={\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}b},
      nodes near coords={\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}b},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=year, y=assets] {\endowment};
\end{axis} 
\node [anchor=south, yshift=3ex] at ($(left axis.outer north east)!0.5!(right axis.outer north west)$)
            {\large Harvard Endowment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```