# Error when parsing tikzpicture with a Greek letter in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

After trying to reparse a LaTeX document with another parser on another OS :

```
\documentclass[ a4paper,
            11pt,
            BCOR=12mm,
            DIV=18,
            abstract=on,
            headinclude,
            twoside,
            appendixprefix=true]{scrreprt} %twoside

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{subcaption}       %
\usepackage{placeins}               %FloatBarrier
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}     %Enables appendix; added to table of contents
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}       %Bilder nicht unter Fussnote, falls mit b gesetzt
\usepackage{footnote}               %Footnotes in tables
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}      %URLs       LOAD LAST
\usepackage{dsfont}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}


%\unitlength=0.7mm
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52786/din-conform-arrowheads-and-hatching-in-tikz
\pgfarrowsdeclare{DIN}{DIN}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.15\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=7.29\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.6\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=.6\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by1.7\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.15\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetmiterjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{-4mm}{0.5mm}}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{-4mm}{-0.5mm}}}
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{DIN reversed}{DIN reversed}{DIN}{DIN}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Results and Conclusion}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={$\alpha$, $a$},
        width = 1.0\textwidth,
        height  = 260pt,
        ylabel = {Impact},
        xlabel = {Paramter},
        ytick=\empty,ymin=0,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        enlarge x limits=0.3,
        bar width=100pt,
        axis line style={-DIN,ultra thin},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        ylabel near ticks,
        xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-3mm},
        xtick style={draw=none},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.south east)},anchor=north west}
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=white] coordinates {
        ($\alpha$, 1)
        ($a$, 2)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I got this error message:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   < to be read again>
>
> \alpha
>   l.97 ]
>   The control sequence marked  should
>   not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Note that it depends on the Greek letter `\alpha` if it is replaced by a roman one it works fine. Why can you not write a control sequence as a label here?

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

The PGF Versions installed are:

> pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
>
> pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
>
> pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
>
> pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
>
> pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
>
> pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
>
> pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
>
> pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
>
> pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
>
> ...

Comment: I do not get any error with `pgfplots` v1.12. Which version you are using?

Comment: Don't load `ucs` along with the `utf8` option to `inputenc`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek How do I get the version you mean?

Comment: @egreg Thx for the hint. But comment this line out does not help.

Comment: @Matthias For example, the `.log` file contains `Package pgfplots YYYY/MM/DD vX.Y ...` with the date `YYYY/MM/DD` and the version `X.Y`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek THX. See my edit. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Matthias The edit misses the version for `pgfplots`. But the `pgf` stuff is quite old, thus it is likely, that you need an update (both `pgf`/TikZ and `pgfplots` at least).